# What is parity of charge?

Tags: condensed-matter, charge, gauge-theory, ising-model, parity

In the book *Field Theories of Condensed Matter Physics* by Fradkin:

When discussing the gauge-invariant operators of $Z_2$ lattice gauge theory in Page 299, the author says

> Owing to the $Z_2$ symmetry, only the parity of the charge is well defined.

What does "parity of charge" mean? And why only it is well defined?

Answer (score 1):

Charge parity conservation means that charge is conserved modulo 2. This is because of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ nature of the symmetry (as opposed to usual $U(1)$).

Another way to see this is that by starting from a state with two charge one particles close together, we can annihilate them into the charge-free state using gauge invariant local operators.

Parity usually refers to whether something is even/odd. By "only parity of charge is well-defined", Fradkin means that if you have a configuration with many charges, it belongs to the same symmetry sector as the state with $N\pm 2$ charges (because of aforementioned annihilation), and so on. In other words, a symmetric eigenstate of the Hamiltonian is a superposition of states with different total $N$, but it will be an eigenstate of $(-1)^\hat{N}$. This is the operator that measures the evenness / oddness of $N$, and is called the charge parity operator.

To rephrase Fradkin,

> Given an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, only the parity of the charge is well defined owing to its $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. The eigenstate will not have definite $\hat{N}$ but it will have definite $(-1)^\hat{N}$.